# MVC Multiple AJAX Requests with Entity Framework causes error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, jqgrid, castle-windsor

I have two jqGrids that load data via an ajax POST call to my controller and each time I run the application, only one of the two POSTs executes successfully. Normally, if i hit refresh on the browser, both grids will load correctly. But consistently 1 of the 2 fail on first load of each view ( i have two views/pages that each have 2 jqGrids, "dashboard style"). In log4net logs the two requests have different threads and one always fails while the other succeeds but which one succeeds is random (probably first-come, first-serve)... Sometimes i get a null reference error when it tries to iterate through a resulting enumerable list of items, other times i get "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."

I have some suspicions of what might be the cause of this: EF lazy loading/proxies enabled, bad windsor configuration, automapper error that is not being thrown or shown in stack trace. But since i really have no clue, below is my setup in case it helps decipher this one.

**Persistence** [LifestyleSingleton] - This holds the EF4 datacontext (code-first) and a reference to EF4.3. There's a factory for creating the Context called GetContext() and this factory implements IDisposable.
**Repo** [LifestylePerWebRequest] - This holds repositories implementing the repository and specification pattern (http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/).
**Services** [LifestylePerWebRequest] - Calls onto repo and applies bus logic, i.e. returns PagedList objects for UI paging.
**Controllers** [LifestyleTransient] - mvc controllers, make use of automapper for mapping to view model types.
**MVC UI** - I'm implementing Lib.Web.MVC which creates a strongly-typed wrapper for jqGrid. And from here, I use windsor container to do DI.

UPDATE: I changed all components to register with LifestylePerThread and all of the errors seem to have been resolved with this. However, I do not understand why.. I'm new to DI so I'm sure i'm missing something. **Could someone please explain why this has solved the issue?** And what will this change do as far as scalability...? I figured I'd want the context factory along with the context itself to be registered as singleton's but that obviously wasn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the identical issue, also using Huy Nguyen's repository. I'm not using Windsor and I don't see how AutoMapper could have anything to do with this.

I resolved it by adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to my connection string.

Quoting Microsoft   "Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is.... In a nutshell, it is the ability to have more than one pending request under a given SQL Server connection. For most cases this will directly translate to the ability to have more than one default result set (firehose cursor) outstanding while other operations can execute within the same session."

Read more about MARS at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

As for your repository 'lifestyle' I suggest creating a new instance of the repository each time one is requested. I've had problems with per request.

I've determined that the two threads are accessing the same context and that seems to be a problem. The first executing thread hasn't had time to close and the second is ending up with the same context.

Comment: I actually ran into this roadblock earlier on in my development and I solved it by enablind MARS. So then I should set repository and service classes to LifestyleTransient() ?

Comment: I agree with this too. You should not be instantiating repositories by application or "by web request" either. However, we have a service layer and we will use the same repository within the service call if it's there safe in the knowledge that all get's disposed at the end of the service request. Datacontext creation can become epensive and you can run into big problems if you load from 1 repository then try and save it in another (attach/detach/setobjectstate).

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned earlier I was having an identical issue using the same repository. I think I've resolved it using a solution I found in a [post](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern-upgraded-to-ef-4-1/#comment-538) on Huy Nguyen's (the repository's author) Blog.

> .... when I used this repository in a batch process whereby multiple
>   threads are accessing the repository along with the simple
>   objectcontext storage, I got exceptions since an objectcontext cannot
>   be shared (EF is by itself not threadsafe due to this). Therefore,
>   with a small modification to the SimpleObjectContextStorage it seems
>   to work now as well: I simply made the storage variable threadstatic
>   and used the property in the other methods instead (_storage is
>   duplicated per thread, but only filled in for the first thread via the
>   static constructor call) [ThreadStatic] private static Dictionary
>   _storage;
>
> private static Dictionary Storage { get { return _storage ?? (_storage
>   = new Dictionary()); } } note: ThreadStatic expects the corresponding variable to be static as well, but since you typically define only one
>   storage per app via the ObjectContextManager.Init call, this shouldn’t
>   have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

How does it fail? ie are you getting an exception back? Do you uses something like firebug to see what's being returned?

Session will lock and only alow serial requests will be processed so if session is involved in your concurrent requests you might be getting problems too.

EDIT: As a basic rule if anything is causing your repositories to be instantiated and datacontexts to remain undisposed across requests, then this is a very very bad thing. I have seen a lot of IOC containers that allow this to happen far too easily either by configuration or by binding to something that's supposed to be per request.

Go through your stack trace and check that repository constructors are not being bootstrapped to the application scope. This will also lead losing thread safety... very common with off the shelf dependancy injection and why I write my own so I know what's going on.

Scenario I encountered [here](http://stuartgatenby.com/aspnet/2011/02/27/structuremap-thread-safety-dangers-of-pattern-chasing/)

PS: If you're doing 2 seperate posts via ajax, then you shouldn't need multiple active result sets and that is a sign that your repo and/or datacontext are boud outside of request scope. You should only need multiple active result sets if you want to create 2 instances of the same datacontext within the same request scope.

If it is a single post/request, then above answer is probably the right one.

Comment: I have the errhandler filter applied globally so then my ajax action throws the exception i've updated the posting with. 

I"m not exactly sure what you mean by "session will lock", could you elaborate? I'm not using any session variables yet, but does this mean if I make use of session variable i'm unable to make concurrent/async requests without lock issues?

Comment: oh, and return is just internal server error. no details from jqGrid onError event.

Comment: Yes, if session is enabled, then the framework will serialize your incoming requests. When processing multiple requests from a session the running request will block the others until complete. To work around this you have to use an asynchronous Controller. See this MS article for a good overview, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx .